# Why is python3 not finding a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Running my script (which imports ply) with python 2.7 works without issue. But trying to run the same script with python3 causes the following. (Note: I'm on v3.10 of ply - the latest which should be compatible with python3).

```
bos-mpqpu:config_parse rabdelaz$ python3 lexparse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lexparse.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ply.lex as lex
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ply'
bos-mpqpu:config_parse rabdelaz$ pip show ply | grep Version
Version: 3.10
```

I've installed python3:

```
 bos-mpqpu:config_parse rabdelaz$ python3
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ply
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ply'
>>>
```

Comment: Did you install it on Python 3?

Comment: yes. (updated post)

Comment: Did you install *the module* on Python 3?

Comment: Don't you have a pip3 executable ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, please explain.

Comment: Python 2 and Python 3 don't share modules and check for compatibility. Their modules are entirely separate; installing a module for Python 2 doesn't affect Python 3.

Comment: so how would i install a module for python3?

Comment: sweet jesus with the downvotes. what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install this module for python3.

Python modules, libraries are different for python 2 and 3.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: Try running pip3 install ply. Don't forget to type sudo before the command if you're on a LInux

Answer (score 5):

Try this command if you have pip3

```
pip3 install ply
```

This works too:

```
python3 -m pip install ply
```

Answer (score 0):

for linux installation:

python 2.7.x : sudo apt-get install python-ply

python 3.x : sudo apt-get install python3-ply

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/utopic/python-ply

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but couldn't exactly know what was the problem so I again installed ply library and went to its location and made my project there. Library worked well there.

1. Install ply library

   pip3 install ply
   this would show you where the library is stored after successful installation.
2. Go to the location and make your project their.

This worked for me. Hopefully it would help you too.